# Odd numbers to the power of 2^n modulo 2^(n+1)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am a high-school math student. I found a pattern a while ago - given n, an odd positive integer, and r, any positive integer power of two, n^r modulo 2r always equals 1. I was trying to find a proof of this, but I could not find anything. I am asking whether there is any way to get any progress on this problem, or a theorem that states this.

Edit - The problem is solved using Euler's theorem or via an induction argument.

Comment: Do you know the binomial theorem?

Comment: I do, but how could I prove that the binomial coefficient times the power of 2 is divisible by twice the power of 2?

Comment: See  [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), which is the generalization of Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Oh, this finishes the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apart from Euler's theorem, it can also be proved straightforwardly by induction on the power of 2.

**To prove:**  $(2k+1)^{(2^r)} \equiv 1 \mod {2^{r+1}}$ for all $r\in\mathbb{N}$.

This is obviously true for $r=0$, because $2k+1\equiv 1 \bmod 2$.

Suppose if is true for a particular value of $r$. Then:
$$(2k+1)^{(2^r)} = 1+m\cdot 2^{r+1}$$
Square both sides:
$$(2k+1)^{(2^{r+1})} = (1+m\cdot 2^{r+1})^2\\
(2k+1)^{(2^{r+1})} = 1+2m\cdot 2^{r+1} + m^2 2^{2r+2}\\
(2k+1)^{(2^{r+1})} = 1+(m+m^2 2^r)\cdot 2^{r+2}\\
(2k+1)^{(2^{r+1})} \equiv 1 \mod 2^{r+2}$$
which means it is also true for $r+1$.
Therefore by induction the statement is true for all values $r\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).